How to organize models for complex appointment system in Django?
I want to create a project that gives an opportunity for patients and staff to make appointments to the dentist. Appointment can contain one or many services. Each service can have one of two durations(30 min or 60 min). Therefore, appointment can have different durations that are multiples of 30 minutes. I want to organize time management using slots of 30 min so if appointment contain one 30 min and one 60 min service, it takes 3 slots that become unavailable for other users. What is the best way to organize all this stuff?
It's very important to have an opportunity to automatically summarize durations of all services (which are in appointment) and somehow save this information in db to show new patients, which time periods are free.
Thank you so much for answers <3
